TypeError: (0 , _utils___WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default) is not a function
I'm having issues with Shadcn library, after fixing all the style problems I encounter issues with the import of cn.
Next.js point me cn isn't a function. I tried to do
import { cn } from '/utils/' and import cn from '/utils/' and even changing the route of import.
I tried to do default export of the component. But I didn't success.
import { cn } from '/utils/'

const Separator = React.forwardRef((
  { className, orientation = "horizontal", decorative = true, ...props },
  ref
) => (
  <SeparatorPrimitive.Root
    ref={ref}
    decorative={decorative}
    orientation={orientation}
    className={cn(
      "shrink-0 bg-border",
      orientation === "horizontal" ? "h-[1px] w-full" : "h-full w-[1px]",
      className
    )}
    {...props} />
))
Separator.displayName = SeparatorPrimitive.Root.displayName

export { Separator }

That the separator component, and below is the cn utility.
import { clsx } from 'clsx'
import { twMerge } from 'tailwind-merge'

export function cn(...inputs) {
    return twMerge(clsx(inputs))
}

I already tried multiple approaches from other import issues similar like this, changing between routes, putting brackets, etc. But none of them didn't solve my issue.

Why not using the cn function from clsx. You can import via:


import cn from "clsx"



